# Catalogue of topological properties of well known spaces

Tags: general-topology

I'm looking for collections of topological properties of well known spaces. For example, classification by separation axioms, compactness, connectivity, homotopy, homology, ... of $T^n$, $RP^n$, ..., topologist's sine curve, combs, ... If it contains more exotic spaces, it would be more helpful. I know [manifold atlas project](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Main_Page). Any other suggestion would be helpful.

---

Edit: Any topological properties are good but I'm slightly more interested in the collection of algebraic topological "numbers", such as Betti number, torsion coefficients, ... .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good resource, based on the book “counterexamples in topology “ is [pi base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces)

Comment: Wow, the site looks very interesting. Thank you.